# sapui5 conditional icon for list

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I can't find how I make an item in the list show an icon based on a property of the model. I want the icon to be different depending on the property 'answer'.

This is the code in my view:

```
createContent: function(oController){
    var self = this;

    this.oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
        title : "{title}",
        icon : self.getIcon("{answer}"),
        type : sap.m.ListType.Active,
        press: [oController.onListSelect, oController]
    });

    // etc..
},


getIcon : function(answer){
    alert(answer);
    // some logic here to return the icon based on property 'answer'
}
```

The problem with this code is that the property 'answer' is not passed to the method `getIcon`. Instead it just passes the string `{answer}`

Comment: I haven't been using sapui5 in a while, but IIRC it should be doable with `this.getProperty('answer')` in the getIcon function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a formatter function:

```
icon : {
    parts : ["answer"],
    formatter : function(answerValue){
        return self.getIcon(answerValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get an error though on the 'parts' saying 'answer is not defined'.

Comment: My bad, it should have been between quotes... Have updated the answer